# How to obtain a single output from a CNN while we feed it multiple number of colour images?

Tags: tensorflow, deep-learning, conv-neural-network, reinforcement-learning, q-learning

I am doing a Deep-Q Learning task, and I have a sequence of 4 images that I have defined as a state. 
Now I want to feed these 4 images in a CNN and obtain the softmax of the outputs as to what action to take then. 
So how do I do this? Cause 4 images will produce 4 softmax outputs for each image with the basic LeNet structure. 
Does anyone have any solutions or link to articles that can help me here?

Comment: Your assumption that 4 images will produce 4 softmax outputs is wrong, Images are usually 3-channel (RGB), so you just need to input a 4-channel image.

Comment: @MatiasValdenegro I know that I could grayscale the images and put 4 the images in the channels dimension instead. But the thing is, what if I need to work with color images? That makes the input 5 dimensional. Batch_sz x 4_state_images x H x W x Color. Any work around if I don’t wanna use Conv3D?

Comment: No, you should stack (concatenate) along the channels dimension, where you will have an array (samples, w, h, 4 * num_channels)

Comment: @MatiasValdenegro Oh, okay, I didn’t know that could be done without messing up the information in my images. Thank you! :)